# Finding substring in assembly

Tags: algorithm, string, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm wondering if there is a more efficient method to finding a substring in assembly then what I am currently planning to do.

I know the string instruction "scansb/scasw/scads" can compare a value in EAX to a value addressed by EDI. However, as far as I understand, I can only search for one character at a time using this methodology.

So, if I want to find the location of "help" in string "pleasehelpme", I could use scansb to find the offset of the h, then jump to another function where I compare the remainder. If the remainder isn't correct, I jump back to scansb and try searching again, this time after the previous offset mark.

However, I would hate to do this and then discover there is a more efficient method. Any advice? Thanks in advance

Comment: I doubt if there is any better way. You might want to look at this implementation in AOA, but it seems to be same: http://maven.smith.edu/~thiebaut/ArtOfAssembly/CH15/CH15-4.html#HEADING4-3

Comment: Also see [Agner Fog's strstr() vs g++ built-in strstr() performance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48601519/608639).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are indeed more efficient ways, both instruction-wise and algorithmically.

If you have the hardware you can use the sse 4.2 compare string functions, which are very fast. See an overview http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/composer/en-us/2009/compiler_c/intref_cls/common/intref_sse42_comp.htm and an example using the C instrinsics http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/xml-parsing-accelerator-with-intel-streaming-simd-extensions-4-intel-sse4/

If you have long substrings or multiple search patterns, the [Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm), [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) and [Rabin-Karp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_string_search_algorithm) algorithms may be more efficient.

Comment: +1 Excellent point. Thinks advanced quite a bit since I've studied asm.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a more efficient method (only some optimizations that can be done to this method). Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874204/masm-str-and-substr) might be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

`scansb` is the assembly variant for `strcmp`, not for `strstr`. if you want a really efficient method, then you have to use better algorithm.

For example, if you search in a long string, then you could try some special algorithms: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm