# Agner Fog's strstr() vs g++ built-in strstr() performance

Tags: c++, strstr

I attempted to compare the built-in strstr() in g++ (g++ (Debian 7.2.0-19) with the assembly implementation in Agner Fog's asmlib (http://www.agner.org/optimize/asmlib.zip).  The target CPU is core-i3 supporting sse4x and avx.

To compile:

```
g++  -O2  -msse4  main.cpp libaelf64.a
```

(you would need the static library is from the asmlib distribution).

Functions rdtsc64_start(), rdtsc64_end() to measure performance follow intel's white paper (https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/ia-32-ia-64-benchmark-code-execution-paper.pdf)

Provided the technique is correct, A_strstr() from asmlib is about 5 times slower than gcc's strstr(). I am making an effort to go though A_strstr()'s assembly to better understand what is going on, meanwhile, does anyone with (or without) experience with asmlib have an explanation?  Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "asmlib.h"
#include <cstdint>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

inline __attribute__ ((always_inline))
static uint64_t rdtsc64_start() {
    unsigned long cycles_high, cycles_low;
    asm volatile (
            "CPUID\n\t"
            "RDTSC\n\t"
            "mov %%rdx, %0\n\t"
            "mov %%rax, %1\n\t": "=r" (cycles_high), "=r"
            (cycles_low):: "%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx");
    return ((uint64_t)cycles_high << 32) | cycles_low;
}

inline __attribute__ ((always_inline))
static uint64_t rdtsc64_end() {
    unsigned long cycles_high, cycles_low;
    asm volatile(
            "RDTSCP\n\t"
            "mov %%rdx, %0\n\t"
            "mov %%rax, %1\n\t"
            "CPUID\n\t": "=r" (cycles_high), "=r"
            (cycles_low):: "%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx");
    return ((uint64_t)cycles_high << 32) | cycles_low;
}

static void rdtsc64_warmup() {
    unsigned long cycles_high, cycles_low;
    asm volatile (
            "CPUID\n\t"
            "RDTSC\n\t"
            "mov %%rdx, %0\n\t"
            "mov %%rax, %1\n\t": "=r" (cycles_high), "=r" (cycles_low)::
            "%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx");
    asm volatile(
            "RDTSCP\n\t"
            "mov %%rdx, %0\n\t"
            "mov %%rax, %1\n\t"
            "CPUID\n\t": "=r" (cycles_high), "=r" (cycles_low):: "%rax",
            "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx");
    asm volatile (
            "CPUID\n\t"
            "RDTSC\n\t"
            "mov %%rdx, %0\n\t"
            "mov %%rax, %1\n\t": "=r" (cycles_high), "=r" (cycles_low)::
            "%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx");
    asm volatile(
            "RDTSCP\n\t"
            "mov %%rdx, %0\n\t"
            "mov %%rax, %1\n\t"
            "CPUID\n\t": "=r" (cycles_high), "=r" (cycles_low):: "%rax",
            "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx");
}

int main(void) {
    char a[] = "This is a very long string with a WORD inside.";
    char b[] = "WORD";
    char *p = nullptr;

    rdtsc64_warmup();
    int64_t start = rdtsc64_start();
    for (volatile int64_t i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i) {
        char *p = ::strstr(a,b);
    }
    int64_t end = rdtsc64_end();
    std::cerr << "strstr, counter=  " << (end - start) << std::endl;

    rdtsc64_warmup();
    start = rdtsc64_start();
    for (volatile int64_t i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i) {
        char *p = A_strstr(a, b);
    }
    end = rdtsc64_end();
    std::cerr << "A_strstr, counter=" << (end - start) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `asmlib` version is going to have the overhead of actually calling a function while the `stdlib` version of `strstr()` is handled as a builtin by GCC, so it is likely inlined.  You might want to see how things compare if you use the `-fno-builtin` option.

Comment: And since the contents of `a` and `b` are known at compile time GCC could in principle optimize the call to `::strstr()` away completely. Actually it's probably doing that anyway since the result of the call to `::strstr()` is being discarded. You should really examine the assembly code generated.

Comment: I tried -fno-inline -fno-builtin options, the result was the same.  I'll start looking at the assembly. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: You were right.  With '-fno-inline -fno-builtin', I looked at the assembly, and didn't see any calls to the standard strstr().  It was obviously compiled away because nothing depends on the result, like you said. I introduced a dependency -- stored results of strstr() and A_strstr() in an array of pointers, and printed the difference.  Quite nonsensical, but it brought the strstr() call back.  Now A_strstr() beats the built-in version by a factor of 4.